# jNetPcap Packet discard if coming from specific IP address

Tags: packets, jnetpcap

I am trying to filter the packet and discard if expression matches the situation. I mean to say that If packet is coming from 192.168.1.100, It should not get deliver to the destination(which is 192.168.1.119).

```
<pre>PcapBpfProgram program = new PcapBpfProgram();
String expression = "host 192.168.1.100";
int optimize = 0;         
int netmask = 0xFFFFFF00; 

if (pcap.compile(program, expression, optimize, netmask) != Pcap.OK
{                                                  
   System.err.println(pcap.getErr());
   return;
}                               
if (pcap.setFilter(program) != Pcap.OK)
{                                           
 System.err.println(pcap.getErr()); 
 return;        
}</pre>
```

In my CASE the host is 192.168.1.100 so **Pcap.OK** is returning true. But packet is still transmitting to the destination. How can I stop that packet from transmission???

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently built a packet sniffer that redirected particular RTP packets to a different detination, I guess it is exactly what you need to do. You can get the whole code from my GitHub repository, under the "Lizardous" folder:

https://github.com/Longhitano/main_projects/blob/master/Lizardous/src/j1/lizardous.java